# Scala generic generator type

Tags: scala

I am working on a function which will create  a generic generator of type S.
I am using Arbitary[Int] to get dynamic sequence count, but I am not getting how to use it to generate that many objects of type S.

Here is my partial functional:

```
type S

val genFunc: Gen[S] = {    
  // arbitary int value for sequence number
  //sequenceCount <- Arbitary[Int]   

  // generate S type
  // for {  sequence <- 0 to sequenceCount
  //        generatedObject <- generator   // is this a valid statement? 
  //     } yield (sequence, generatedObject)

// def generator: S = ???
}
```

Should I be using generator function to abstract out the actual implementation of generating S type objects?

At runtime I will get the actual data type I want to generate.

Comment: The usual approach to building complex generators is to compose the primitive ones provided by the framework. What this means in practice is that you need to know what the type S is. Is that correct in your case? Or is it completely abstract?

Comment: The function only contains the abstract type. The test suite passes the actual type at runtime.

Comment: Then how are you expected to generate a random instance if you don't know what the type is?

Comment: That is the problem. But for test case assigns type S = List[Node]. But even with that my generator cannot be generating list object directly. I wanted to keep the type abstraction intact. Any other way this can be solved?